# Windows encrypted files can't be opened on macOS

Tags: windows, macos, efs

I have encrypted certain folders in my hard drive using Windows encryption. I also created an encryption certificate `.pfx` so that I could read those files by installing the certificate. I want to open those encrypted files in my Mac. So I just installed the certificate on my Mac. But I still can't read those files. Can someone tell me how can read and write those files just like I did when I used Windows? (Automatically handles the encryption once the certificate is installed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows encrypts files using the transparent Encrypted File System (EFS).

The EFS encryption system is proprietary and is not supported by macOS. Therefore installing the certificate and private key into macOS has no effect as macOS does not know how to handle EFS files.

There might exists third party programs for macOS that make it possible to manually decrypt/read or maybe even write EFS encrypted files, however this just theory. I don't know if such tools really exist.